# Why does Co(CO)4 exist as dimeric Co2(CO)8?

Tags: coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

I was wondering why is this equilibrium below established at all... Why can't Co(CO)4 exist on its own, as a monomer?

[image]

Comment: Reference [5](https://doi.org/10.1021%2Fic50168a037) in the corresponding [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicobalt_octacarbonyl) article gives a lot of information if not the complete answer.

Comment: Also note that the monomer you speak of is not a neutral molecule. It is actually charged, $\ce{[Co(CO)4]-}$. See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97571/why-is-the-oxidation-state-of-co-1-in-coco4

Comment: @NilayGhosh The monomer in this case *is* the (17 electron) neutral Co(CO)4 molecule; [Co(CO)4]− is a different entity. c.f. NO2, N2O4 and NO2-